# Why is SFDX deploy throwing a false warning/error regarding forceignore v2 and double asterisk wildcard? (**\.*)

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, .forceignore

The message warns about `**\.*` even though that isn't present in the forceignore file.

```
    (node:436) Warning: The .forceignore file doesn't adhere to .gitignore format which will be the default behavior starting in Spring '21 release. More information on .gitignore format here: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore. Fix the following lines in your .forceignore and add '# .forceignore v2' to your .forceignore file to switch to the new behavior.
    (node:436) Warning:     **\.*
    ERROR running force:source:deploy:  Unexpected file found in package directory: C:\something\something\something\something\something\main\default\lwc\jsconfig.json
```

The only relevant lines are the following, which look valid according to the docs linked, and worked in v1.

```
**/jsconfig.json
**/.eslintrc.json
```

I am thinking that to workaround this instance I am just going to hardcode the full path to the problem file and remove the wildcard version.

From @[Christian Szandor Knapp](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/324025/why-is-sfdx-deploy-throwing-a-false-warning-error-regarding-forceignore-v2-and-d/324037#comment480478_324025)'s [reported issue](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/690), it sounds like the problems are worse on salesforcedx >=50 and that rolling back to salesforcedx@49.13.1 is helping.  It also sounds like these bugs are being worked on.  Hopefully they can be fixed soon.

My installed version is:

```
> sfdx --version
sfdx-cli/7.75.1-5585088c75 win32-x64 node-v12.18.3

> sfdx plugins --core
@oclif/plugin-autocomplete 0.1.5 (core)
@oclif/plugin-commands 1.3.0 (core)
@oclif/plugin-not-found 1.2.4 (core)
@oclif/plugin-plugins 1.9.0 (core)
@oclif/plugin-warn-if-update-available 1.7.0 (core)
@oclif/plugin-which 1.0.3 (core)
@salesforce/lwc-dev-server 2.5.1
├─ @oclif/plugin-help 2.2.3
└─ @oclif/plugin-update 1.3.9
@salesforce/sfdx-trust 3.4.3 (core)
alias 1.1.2 (core)
analytics 1.12.1 (core)
config 1.1.8 (core)
generator 1.1.3 (core)
salesforcedx 49.13.1 (core)
├─ custom-metadata 1.0.10 (core)
├─ templates 49.9.1 (core)
├─ salesforce-alm 49.12.2 (core)
├─ @salesforce/sfdx-plugin-lwc-test 0.1.7 (core)
└─ apex 0.1.1 (core)
sfdx-cli 7.75.1 (core)
```

Comment: Did you add the v2 comment to use v2?

Comment: Yes. I added that `# .forceignore v2` comment.  Before adding it was just a warning.  After it was the same warning plus the error about the specific file.

Comment: Am seeing the same with with the following file:

` 
# .forceignore v2

package.xml

# LWC configuration files
**/jsconfig.json
**/.eslintrc.json

# LWC Jest
**/__mocks__/**
**/__tests__/**
 `

running sfdx 50.1.1, sfdx-cli 7.76.1

Comment: I've created an issue: https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/690

Comment: Some background that might be useful, there is a default rule being appended to the .forceignore contents for `**/.*`. This gets converted into `**\.*` on Windows as shown in the message. The warning is shown because the old and new libraries used for .gitignore handling don't agree on how to interpret this for .eslintrc.json.

Looking at the doc for new method (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ignore) I suspect it really needed to be `**\\.*` to work. I got the problem on Win7 using just force:project:create without any changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> An update to salesforcedx latest-rc made today should hopefully fix these issues. This will become the default core version shipped with the CLI release planned for this Thursday.
> You can try the fixes made in the latest-rc by: `sfdx plugins:install salesforcedx@latest-rc`

https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/690#issuecomment-716869356

I no longer get the error or warning on `salesforcedx 50.3.1`.

Comment: The `salesforcedx` plugin is deprecated.  Installing it manually via `sfdx plugins:install salesforcedx` is no longer supported and can result in duplicate commands and outdated plugins. [Link](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/1016)

Answer (score 1):

After re-reading the docs, I changed it to this and no longer get the error.  But still get the warning.

```
jsconfig.json
.eslintrc.json
```

Comment: But this only fixes the classes and others will not retrieved for me

Answer (score 0):

Add it `.forceignore v2` as 1st line of `.forceignore` file.

Comment: Get the same warning with `# .forceignore v2` as the first line of the .forceignore file.

Answer (score 0):

```
**/jsconfig.json

**/.eslintrc.json

**profiles

**/*SessionSetting
```

The above are the valid formats and I'm not seeing any error or warning with the above configuration. However the below format will throw the warning

```
*PasswordPolicy
```

Which needs to be changed to

```
.PasswordPolicy
```